# Python Numpy methods correspond to C++ Eigen make crash

Tags: c++, python-3.x, numpy, eigen

I have a NumPy arithmetic needs to translate C++ with Eigen.

```
# D is a 20001x13 matrix stacked from Dva and Dvb, then multiply by w_f.
# dtype=complex<double>
D = np.column_stack((Dva, Dvb)) * w_f.reshape((20001, 1)) * np.ones((1, 13))
R = np.dot(D.conj().T, D)
```

Here is my C++ code (Minimal test):

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

typedef complex<double> dcomplex;

void foo()
{
    vector<dcomplex> wf;
    wf.resize(20001);
    Eigen::Matrix<dcomplex, 20001, 13> *tmp_1 = new Eigen::Matrix<dcomplex, 20001, 13>;
    Eigen::Matrix<dcomplex, 20001, 13> *tmp_2 = new Eigen::Matrix<dcomplex, 20001, 13>;
    Eigen::Matrix<dcomplex, 20001, 7> *Dva = new Eigen::Matrix<dcomplex, 20001, 7>;
    Eigen::Matrix<dcomplex, 20001, 6> *Dvb = new Eigen::Matrix<dcomplex, 20001, 6>;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20001; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            (*Dva)(i, j) = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            (*Dvb)(i, j) = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
            (*tmp_2)(i, j) = wf[i];
    }
    *tmp_1 << *Dva, *Dvb;
    auto *D = &tmp_1->cwiseProduct(*tmp_2);

    auto R = (D->transpose() * (*D));
    R(0,0);
}
```

The shape of matrix R is 13x13 in Eigen, which is same as NumPy. But the variable R can't be indicated in C++.

```
R.rows() == 13;  // true
R.cols() == 13;  // true
R(0, 0);  // or what ever makes it crash
```

Raised the exception "0xC00000FD: Stack overflow".

Comment: Do you make your pointers point at anything before trying to use them?

Comment: This is undefined behavior already, unless you initialized `tmp_1` somehow: `(*tmp_1)(i, j) = wf[i]`. Please provide a [mcve] (i.e., including all `#include` and function signatures, and no `...` omissions!

Comment: Also, is there any reason you refer to everything as pointer? `&tmp_1->cwiseProduct(*tmp_2);` should not compile, because you take the address of a temporary: https://godbolt.org/z/Mlv21X

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write the memory allocate expression for tmp_1 and tmp_2. I have updated them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should barely work with `new` in C++ code. Use local objects (or `std::vector`) most of the time, and if necessary use smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

Regarding the Eigen part of your question, avoid fixed sized matrices which are very large (more than a few KiB). You can have one dimension fixed and the other `Dynamic`. And finally, avoid `auto` in combination with Eigen, unless you know what you are doing!

The following should work. I replaced all your loops by corresponding Eigen functionality, and avoided the temporaries by directly doing a product with a diagonal matrix. Alternatively, you could do a `cwiseProduct` with a [`replicate()`d](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1VectorwiseOp.html#a5f0c8dc9e9c4aeaa2057f15800f5c18c) matrix.

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<dcomplex, Eigen::Dynamic,1> VectorXcd;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<dcomplex, Eigen::Dynamic,13> MatrixX13cd;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<dcomplex, Eigen::Dynamic,7> MatrixX7cd;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<dcomplex, Eigen::Dynamic,6> MatrixX6cd;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<dcomplex, 13,13> Matrix13cd;


MatrixX7cd  Dva(20001,  7);
MatrixX6cd  Dvb(20001,  6);

Dva.setZero(); Dvb.setZero();
MatrixX13cd D(20001, 13);
D.leftCols(7).noalias()  = VectorXcd::Map(wf.data(), wf.size()).asDiagonal() * Dva;
D.rightCols(6).noalias() = VectorXcd::Map(wf.data(), wf.size()).asDiagonal() * Dvb;

Matrix13cd R = D.transpose() * D;
```